# how can i auto change the path of my folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

How can i auto set the path of my last directory that i made with my first script in my config file ?

First script

```
//with this script i make my directorys

/* eslint-disable no-sync */
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
const folderName = process.argv[2];

try {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join(folderName));
    console.log('New Directory created successfully');
  }   
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error,'Directory already exists !!');
}
```

config file

```
const config = {
  mongodb: {

    databaseName: 'test',

    options: {
      useNewUrlParser: true, 
      useUnifiedTopology: true 
    }
  },

  // i need to auto set the last path of my directory that i made with my first script

  migrationsDir: './set here the last path',

  changelogCollectionName: 'changelog',

  migrationFileExtension: '.js',


  useFileHash: false,

  moduleSystem: 'esm'
};

export default config;
```

i was thinking to do a command and when i ran it set the path in my migrationsDir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth like this:

```js
// Try to get default settings.
let defaultFolderName;
try {
  defaultFolderName = fs.readFileSync(`./app_settings`, { encoding: 'utf8' });
} catch (error) {}

// Define folder path using ENV and default.
const folderName = process.argv[2] || defaultFolderName;

// Save default settings.
fs.writeFileSync(`./app_settings`, folderName, { encoding: 'utf8' })

//...
```

Comment: what is /app_settings is my config file or is a new file?

Comment: New file created in app directory to save needed settings.

Comment: but how can i position what i'm writing in my var migrationsDir ?